# Elastic scrolling move elements

Tags: html, css

Im figuring out how to move an element when the window elastic scrolls, for example this site http://www.mccarthyarts.com/ moves the first background down a bit whenever we scroll past the site canvas.

Anyone know how this works?

Comment: This technique is called as [parallax scrolling](https://www.google.com/search?q=parallax+scrolling)

Comment: @VenomVendor Nope, it isn't. "Lion introduced a new feature called "elastic scrolling", in which you can scroll past the top or bottom of the window and it'll "bounce back" like a rubber band."

Comment: Try example --> [jquery easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

Comment: @VenomVendor Do you even get what I'm trying to do?, i want the elements to follow the elastic scrolling. Like moving the element down 1px per 1px I elastic scroll the page. How does Jquery Easing do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way this would be achieved would involve listening for scroll events.  Whenever the event is triggered, check if you're passed the bounds of the document.  If you are, then you must be in the elastic area.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("scroll", function() {
        var scrollAmount = $(this).scrollTop();
        var viewHeight = $(window).height();
        var docHeight = $(document).height();

        if (scrollAmount < 0) {
            // Top elastic
        }
        else if (scrollAmount + viewHeight > docHeight) {
            // Bottom elastic
        }
    });
});
```